gpg: error retrieving 'my_user@gmail.com' via WKD: No data
I am trying to write a script where I use 7z on some directories, and then use gpg to encrypt them. journalctl -u backup_encrypt_browser.service tells me :
gpg: error retrieving 'user@gmail.com' via WKD: No data
May 31 09:27:35 user backup_encrypt_browser.sh[21379]: gpg: user@gmail.com: skipped: No data
May 31 09:27:35 user backup_encrypt_browser.sh[21379]: gpg: /home/user/Bookmarks/Home_mozilla-2024_05_31_092449.7z: encryption failed: No data
May 31 09:27:35 user backup_encrypt_browser.sh[21393]: gpg: error retrieving 'user@gmail.com' via WKD: No data

I already have a systemd .service and .timer file set up and it's working, but breaks during the encryption.
The script is very simple :
#!/bin/bash
  
  # Directories to back up
  BACKUP_DIRS="/home/user/.mozilla"
  BACKUP_DIRS2="/home/user/.var/app/io.gitlab.librewolf-community/.librewolf"
  
  # Backup destination
  BACKUP_DEST="/home/user/Bookmarks"
  
  # GPG recipient key
  GPG_RECIPIENT="user@gmail.com"
  
  # Set the home directory for GPG
  GPG_HOMEDIR="/home/user/.gnupg"
  
  # Create a timestamp
  TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")
  
  # Backup file name
  BACKUP_FILE="${BACKUP_DEST}/Home_mozilla-${TIMESTAMP}.7z"
  BACKUP_FILE2="${BACKUP_DEST}/Home_librewolf-${TIMESTAMP}.7z"
  
  # Create the backup
  7z a -mhe=on -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mmt=on -mhe=on "$BACKUP_FILE" $BACKUP_DIRS
  7z a -mhe=on -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mmt=on -mhe=on "$BACKUP_FILE2" $BACKUP_DIRS2
  
  # Encrypt the backup
  gpg -vv --output "${BACKUP_FILE}.gpg" --encrypt --recipient "$GPG_RECIPIENT" "$BACKUP_FILE"
  gpg -vv --output "${BACKUP_FILE2}.gpg" --encrypt --recipient "$GPG_RECIPIENT" "$BACKUP_FILE2"
  
  # Remove the unencrypted backup file
  #rm -v "$BACKUP_FILE" "$BACKUP_FILE2"
  
  chown user:user "${BACKUP_FILE}" "${BACKUP_FILE2}"

Not sure why it can't find the keys locally and encrypt them. Any help is appreciated.
